# Does it matter if a company is incorporated in Delaware?

Tags: united-states, contracts, legal, company

I may start working for a US company operating in state X but incorporated in Delaware. I've heard companies do it because Delaware corporate law is somehow convenient to companies, but I don't know the details.

Should this matter to me as a potential consultant or potential employee?

Comment: No.  It is very common.

Comment: @acpilot: The fact that it's common does not mean that it doesn't matter...

Comment: Ok.  The answer to your question is "talk to a lawyer."  Maybe try the law stack.

Comment: Is there something specific you're worried about?

Comment: @KentA.: I'd rather not spell out my own concerns; I'd like to hear if there are commonly-known issues with this case.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: That will tell you what's beneficial to the corporation, and in "rosy glasses"; it won't tell you what's potentially bad for employees/contractors of the company.

Answer (score 4):

Google has the answer here.  I just searched for 'Why do companies incorporate in Delaware" and scanned through the  results.

One good link is here:
[The Top 10 Reasons Companies Incorporate in Delaware](http://www.bendlawoffice.com/2011/08/01/reasons-to-incorporate-in-delaware/)

> There are many reasons why more companies are incorporated in Delaware than any other state.  This article highlights a few of the reasons why half a million businesses, including **more than half of all U.S. publicly-traded companies and 60% of Fortune 500 companies, have incorporated in Delaware**. It then outlines the biggest drawbacks to incorporating in Delaware and explains why it is not a one-size-fits-all solution.

The top reason being:

> 1. The Corporate Law Expertise Of The Delaware Court of Chancery
>
> Delaware has a highly respected court that focuses on corporate issues – the Court of Chancery.  Because of this specialization, the Court of Chancery has a great deal of expertise and familiarity in resolving complex corporate disputes.

There's also a few drawbacks listed.

Read the article, and Google some more, then make your own decision.

Bottom line answer:  **No, it doesn't matter.**  If it did matter, then an awful lot of employees/companies are doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Should this matter to me as a potential consultant or potential employee?

Where a company is incorporated should not directly matter to a consultant or employee.

Delaware is the most popular choice outside of the state where a business operates. This is primarily because **established precedents in the Delaware jurisdiction go back to 1792, giving a more predictable and independent legal environment.**

A company still has to qualify for taxes, employment regulations etc in every state of operations.

Comment: Nobody selects a state for incorporation based on the age of the precedents... there are actual reasons for the preference, and I would like to understand whether some of them may affect me.

Comment: I have been through this myself, establishing a Delaware corp for our US operations in connection with a round of VC investment. Delaware was seen as the most reliable option because of the legal predictability and familiarity. The way their legal system is put together really does make a difference, with trial by judge based on precedent seen as favourable to trial by jury.

Comment: Ok, precendent over jury. I understand. My question is, though, would these precedents, say, give employers rights or powers vis-a-vis employees which they may not be able to uphold in other states? E.g. issues like information privacy, intellectual property disputes, liability disputes w.r.t. damage to third parties etc.